# Close the clicked tab, not the currently selected tab JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

I have this class inside my main class to put a close button on my jTabbedPane. The problem is that, for example I have opened three tabs: tab journal, contact, and upload , and the tab contact is the currently selected tab. When I try to close the journal tab which is NOT the selected tab, the one that closes is the currently selected tab.

```
class Tab extends javax.swing.JPanel implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{
    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public Tab(String label){
        super(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        ((java.awt.BorderLayout)this.getLayout()).setHgap(5);
        add(new javax.swing.JLabel(label), java.awt.BorderLayout.WEST);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/timsoftware/images/close.png"));
        javax.swing.JButton closeTab = new javax.swing.JButton(img);
        closeTab.addActionListener(this);
        closeTab.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0,0,0,0));
        closeTab.setBorder(null);
        closeTab.setBorderPainted(false);
        add(closeTab, java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        closeTab();    //function which closes the tab          
    }

}

private void closeTab(){
    menuTabbedPane.remove(menuTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent());
}
```

This is what I do to call the tab :

```
menuTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(menuTabbedPane.indexOfComponent(jvPanel), new Tab("contactPanel"));
```

Comment: [For better help sooner, please include an sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: You appear to remove the *selected component* - which is the currently selected tab.  You need to know the index of the tab you're closing.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry Im new to this. Do I need to create a getter/setter on the tab class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `actionPerformed()` method calls your `closeTab()` method.  Your `closeTab()` method removes the *currently selected tab* from the tabbed pane.

Instead, you need to remove the component that corresponds to your tab with the button that was clicked.

When you create your `Tab`, also pass into the constructor the component that is the tab pane content.  Then, you can use that in your `actionPerformed()` method, and pass the component to `closeTab()`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  closeTab(component);
}

private void closeTab(JComponent component)
{
  menuTabbedPane.remove(component);
}
```

Here's a bit more context:

```
tab = new Tab("The Label", component);          // component is the tab content
menuTabbedPane.insertTab(title, icon, component, tooltip, tabIndex);
menuTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(tabIndex, tab);
```

And in Tab ...

```
public Tab(String label, final JComponent component)
{
  ...
  closeTab.addActionListener(new ActionListner()
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      closeTab(component);
    }
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Greg Should setTabComponentAtIndex(tabIndex, tab) be setTabComponentAt(tabIndex, tab)?  I get an error with the former.

Comment: @JayAvon: looks like yes, it's a typo - I'll edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Greg happy to help and thanks for the help, works like a beauty :D

Answer (score 1):

By removing getSelectedComponent() you will always remove the selected tab, if you want to remove the journal tab you need to pass the journal tab component to the remove method.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry Im new to this. Do I need to create a getter/setter on the tab class?