# Find out which checkbox was selected in custom component tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Consider two classes:

```
public class Test
{
    private boolean skip = false;
    private JLabel label = "";

    public boolean isSkipped()
    {
        return skip;
    }

    public void setSkipped(boolean skip)
    {
        this.skip = skip;
    }

    public void setLabel(String string)
    {
        label.setText(string);
    }
}
```

and `MainWindow` class that we assume that has all fields and methods required for simple frame to be displayed. In this class we also have:

```
private JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
private ArrayList<Test> test = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    test.add(new Test());
}

JPanel checkBoxTab = new JPanel();
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
             test.get(?).setSkipped(true);
        }

        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
        {
             test.get(?).setSkipped(false);
        }

        for(int j = 0, k = 1; j < test.size(); j++)
        {
             if(test.get(j).isSkipped())
             {
                   continue;
             }

             test.get(j).setLabel("" + k);
             k++;
         }
   }
});

   checkBox.setOpaque(false);
   checkBoxTab.add(checkBox);
   checkBoxTab.setOpaque(false);

for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
{
   tabPane.addTab("", test.get(i));
   tabPane.setTabComponentAt(i, checkBoxTab);
}
```

My question is: how do I replace that `?` sign with index of tab that has the chackbox that was selected? I need it to be found dynamically during program run. The purpose of this code is to find out which tab was selected to be skipped, skip it without assigning next number of k to a label and assign next number of k to label in next tab (assuming it's not marked to be skipped, and if it is - repeat previous process). I tried to understand solution in here [Close the clicked tab, not the currently selected tab JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525872/close-the-clicked-tab-not-the-currently-selected-tab-jtabbedpane) but I don't really see how could I implement the "tab content" thing. Depicting previous we have:

```
tabCount: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
skip:     f t f t t f f f t
label:    1   2     3 4 5
```

**EDIT** sorry there was a typo in `MainWindow` class

Comment: What relationship does the `JCheckBox` have to the tab?  Are they contained in the tab header? The tab itself? Or are the separate?

Comment: tab header like in here in the section Tabs with custom components https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: Conceptually, you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553112/how-to-add-close-button-to-a-jtabbedpane-tab/11553266#11553266)

Comment: Hmm, gonna try that tommorow, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Mad Programmer's comment I managed to implement what I wanted

```
checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            test.get(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(tabName)).setSkipped(true);
        }

        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
        {
            test.get(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(tabName)).setSkipped(false);
        }

        for(int j = 0, k = 1; j < test.size(); j++)
        {
            if(test.get(j).isSkipped())
            {
                continue;
            }

            test.get(j).setLabel("" + k);
            k++;
        }
    }
});
```